# A 2-Part Test (or The Squeeze Thm.) Question

Tags: calculus, limits, partial-derivative

> Find the limit, if it exists.

I am sure that one of the paths which uses the line y=mx does not work.

I am not sure for y=x^m because it lead me to 
*mtan(x^2+m^2*x^2)/(x^2+m^2)*

What should I do?

[image: the limit]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzeeu.png)

Comment: In your limit, $y$ is kept fix. Consider two cases: first if $y=0$ and second if $y\neq 0$. In the first case, your function is simply 0 so the limit evaluates to 0. In the second case, your function is continuous at zero and the limit once again evaluates to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider the more general

$$\lim_{x,y\to0} \frac{xy \tan(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}$$

we have that

$$\frac{xy \tan(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}\frac{ \tan(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{ \tan(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\to 1$$

and

$$\frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}\to0$$

indeed consider

$$\frac{|xy|(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}$$

and let

- $x^2=r \cos \theta$
- $y=r \sin \theta$

thus

$$0\le\frac{|xy|(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}=\frac{r^3\,\sqrt r\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}\sin \theta}{r^2}=r\,\sqrt r\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}\sin \theta \to0$$

and for squeeze theorem

$$\frac{|xy|(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}\to 0 \implies \frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}\to0$$